# Java2D: make shapes look less "flat"

Tags: java, graphics

[image]

I'm creating a wheel of fortune like game for kids to learn English online. The issue is that the graphics look terribly flat; I'd like to add some depth (and after that maybe something like bloom or particles). I'm trying to make it appealing to kids aged around 8-12 year old (this game will be used with a teacher during online lessons). The background is OK, I'm more concerned about the slices of the wheel. But any hint would be nice.

This is how I draw them (I'm using the rainbow colors):

```
        int c = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.slices.length; i++) {

            switch (c) {
                case 0: g2d.setPaint(new Color(148, 0, 211)); break;
                case 1: g2d.setPaint(new Color(75, 0, 130)); break;
                case 2: g2d.setPaint(new Color(0, 0, 255)); break;
                case 3: g2d.setPaint(new Color(0, 255, 0)); break;
                case 4: g2d.setPaint(new Color(255, 255, 0)); break;
                case 5: g2d.setPaint(new Color(255, 127, 0)); break;
                case 6: g2d.setPaint(new Color(255, 0, 0)); break;
            }

            c++;
            if (c > 6) c = 0;

            g2d.fill(this.slices[i]);
            g2d.setPaint(new Color(0, 0, 0, 80));
            g2d.draw(this.slices[i]);

        }
```

I guess I can use a gradient fill to make things look better. I tried but I could not make it look nice. The following screenshot gives an idea of a cool looking wheel.

[image]

What can I do to give the wheel a bit more depth and basically make it look cooler?

Comment: Draw it like that? Personally, I wouldn't try to do all this "by hand", I'd use a game library. And probably not Java, but that's a different discussion.

Comment: I'm trying to learn Java: that's the reason I'm using it to develop this mini game (also for some limitations in my company). But I'm not sure about the limitations and how complex it could be to add just a little depth to it.

Comment: It's a little bit complex, but essentially you would need to use multiple gradient fills (to get the high/low lights) and "draw" the borders onto of the fills. Shadowing itself is not "hard", you simply need to use a `AlphaComposite`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is VERY basic example over using multiple paint effects overlapped onto of each other...

[image: Simple]

If I had more time to play around, I might look at using more `RadialGradientPaint` instead of the `LinearGradientPaint`, but this might give you a starting point

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.LinearGradientPaint;
import java.awt.RadialGradientPaint;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Slice slice = new Slice(100, 200, 60, 40);

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            g2d.translate((getWidth() / 2.0) - slice.getBounds().width,
                    (getHeight() - slice.getBounds().height) / 2.0);
            RenderingHints hints = new RenderingHints(
                    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON
            );
            g2d.setRenderingHints(hints);

            Color primaryColor = Color.MAGENTA;
            Color alphaColor = new Color(primaryColor.getRed(), primaryColor.getGreen(), primaryColor.getBlue(), 0);
            Color shadowColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 128);

            g2d.setColor(primaryColor);
            g2d.fill(slice);

            RadialGradientPaint rgp = new RadialGradientPaint(
                    new Point2D.Double(slice.getBounds2D().getWidth(), slice.getBounds2D().getHeight() / 2d), 
                    (float)slice.getBounds2D().getHeight() / 2.0f, 
                    new float[] {0.6f, 1.0f}, 
                    new Color[] {alphaColor, shadowColor});
            g2d.setPaint(rgp);
            g2d.fill(slice);

            Graphics2D gScale = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
            LinearGradientPaint lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(
                    new Point2D.Double(0, 0), 
                    new Point2D.Double(slice.getBounds2D().getWidth(), 0), 
                    new float[]{0f, 1f}, 
                    new Color[] {shadowColor, alphaColor});
            gScale.setPaint(lgp);
            gScale.fill(slice);
            lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(
                    new Point2D.Double(slice.getBounds2D().getWidth(), 0), 
                    new Point2D.Double(slice.getBounds2D().getWidth() * 2, 0), 
                    new float[]{0f, 1f}, 
                    new Color[] {alphaColor, shadowColor});
            gScale.setPaint(lgp);
            gScale.fill(slice);
            gScale.dispose();


            g2d.setPaint(primaryColor.brighter());
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
            g2d.draw(slice);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class Slice extends Path2D.Double {

        public Slice(double width, double height, double range, double innerHeight) {
            moveTo(0, 0);
            append(new Arc2D.Double(0, 0, width, height,
                    90 - (range / 2.0), range,
                    Arc2D.OPEN), false);

            double sliceWidth = width / 2.0;
            double x = (width - sliceWidth) / 2.0;

            append(new Arc2D.Double(x, height, sliceWidth, innerHeight,
                    90 + (range / 2.0), -range,
                    Arc2D.OPEN), true);

            closePath();
        }
    }

}
```